# Access Owner Name and/or Phone Number In Windows Phone 8x Application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In an application that I'm building I would like to have access to the owners name and phone number as part of the profile I'll be creating.  I would like to have those two values auto-populated when they user is on the signup screen just as a nicety.

I have read and always been under the assumption that as a developer we don't have access to this information but I wanted to know if anyone has come up with a unique way of handling this problem or getting at this data.

Comment: You are not able to get the data from the phone, but you can ask the user to enter this information. There is nothing stopping you from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2004/11/28/271110.aspx. It uses c++ code to read phone line number.